# Example of an attack on a message exchange which uses the homomorphic property

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption

Can someone give me an example of an attack on a message exchange using this encryption scheme, that uses the homomorphic property?

In my opinion, Existential forgery under directed message attack uses malleability. Can someone explain it in more detail?

Comment: Please, what do you mean by "message exchange attack"?

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira Like, replay attack or parallel session attack etc.